# Generate report of all the information in a Web Application

Tags: java, web

I am working on a Web Application that sells a Product to users. I would like to create a count of all the times a user buys a product or when the user clicks on a product and doesn't buy it. I want to generate daily, monthly and annual report of this data so that I could eventually analyze this data. How should i approach this problem?. Are there any tools or third party applications that i can use to generate these reports?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a database with users for your web application, you could keep track of purchased and viewed items in the database (and the date these occurred).

To retrieve the reports, you would need to run an aggregate query on your database for the range of time you are looking for. The report itself can most likely be exported by the database you are looking for in CSV format or something like excel.

Answer (score 1):

There are several analytics frameworks out there. For example: [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)

While its main purpose is the analysis of web traffic, it can be also be used to track specific actions (like purchasing) for which you can provide extra data, for example a product id.

The benefit over a handmade solution would be, that it already provides a web interface for data analysis and (automatic) email report generation. If that would be sufficient for your requirements, is up to you of course.